# wsadmin command to re-deploy .war file in WebSphere

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I am a Java developer trying to comeup with a Python script that performs application re-deployment in WebSphere. Can someone clarify if the below command is sufficient for the same? I am aware that the 3rd parameter takes many optional parameters. But I am not too sure which of those are relevant in the case where we want to keep the existing mappings intact.

AdminApp.update(appName, 'app',  '-operation update -contents "warFilePath" ')

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's close, although I think the command has to be an array of strings like below. You also have to save the change to make it stick:

```py
AdminApp.update( appName, 'app', [ '-operation', 'update', '-contents', filePath ] )
AdminConfig.save()
```

You might be interested in [this script](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/simple_script_to_update_enterprise_application), which has additional error handling and cases around those core lines.

Comment: Appreciate your guidance. Thanks much!